# Hide sensitive data in html table column

Tags: jquery, html

I have a html table and the first column has the id. This column is hidden. I have read now this is a bad approach.

But I need this hidden id when the user selects a row and click the delete button to do an ajax post with this id.

Where else should I put this id per row differently and why is this approach bad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the id as an attribute in your table rows. Something like this:

```
<tr data-id="1">
    <td><span class="delete">Delete</span></td>
</tr>

<tr data-id="2">
    <td><span class="delete">Delete</span></td>
</tr>
```

And when the user click on delete or edit, get it with jquery.

```
$('.delete').bind('click', function (e) {
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var id = $row.attr('data-id');

    // now you have `id`
});
```

Comment: I totally forgot about $.data(). In general your answer is ok, I just can`t use this answer as my table is knockoutjs bound and I see no point where I can hook into to add this id to each row. A new question...

Answer (score 5):

Regardless of where you put it, if a particular piece of data is in the HTML transferred to the browser, the user will be able to see it.

You can make it *indirect* by hiding it etc. but doing this won't in any way *secure* it.

My suggestion would to implement some kind of tight access-control-mechanism on the server side that ensures that the person attempting a delete operation has the privilege to do so - than trying to hide things on the client side.

You can also maybe consider applying some kind of encryption to the id prior to sending it to the client so as to make it unguessable.

Comment: I don't know if the poster actually meant "sensitive" in this way, but if so then this is the most _important_ answer.

Comment: ah sorry maybe i put too much weigth on the word sensitive. The id I want to hide per row is an id of a sql field. I just need this id when the user clicks the row to select it and then click the delete button above the table in the button bar.

Comment: @Elisa - Using a hidden input that can be directly *submitted* as in Elliot Nelson's answer should work nicely (as it wont need any additional javascript to read the id and post it to the delete handler).

Comment: @techfoobar I do not want a delete button per row this is against the design of my other views and is a waste of space having 5 and more button on a row for this exists the good old button bar.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a data-attribute for each row element and read it when clicked on row. The advantage here is, data-attribute value is not displayed on the screen.

Comment: a hidden column not either...

Answer (score 0):

Sensitive data as credentials should not be accessible client side. But as i don't know what you call sensitive data, i'll suggest you to use the jquery data object. This have the advantage to keep DOM as clean as possible:

```
//head or any DOM element
$('head').data('key','myValue'); //set
var value = $('head').data('key'); //get
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're already going to have a "Delete button" per row, then the normal convention would be to put the id right into a hidden input field inside each form, like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>John Smith</td>
  <td>37</td>
  <td>
    <form action="/delete">
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="id_for_this_row">
      <button type="submit">Delete</button>
    </form>
  </td>
</tr>
```

This code will work without any Javascript at all. If you then want to enhance the behavior, by making the form post in the background with AJAX, etc., you just add that on top.

If your application is heavily AJAX already, or you cannot use a separate form per `<tr>`, then Sampath's answer would be my go-to (adding a `data-id` attribute to each `<tr>`.)

Comment: I do not use buttons per row that a design failure and waste of space ;-)